# Golang - get list of git remote branches without cloning the repo

Tags: go, git-branch, go-git

I want a list of all the remote branches for a git repo.
Now, this git repo can be private / public. I have the access to the token to access the repo.

I am using this particular SDK : https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5

One way to do this is ..

```
r, cloneErr := git.PlainClone(projectRoot, false, cloneOptions)
remote, err := r.Remote("origin")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
refList, err := remote.List(&git.ListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
refPrefix := "refs/heads/"
for _, ref := range refList {
    refName := ref.Name().String()
    if !strings.HasPrefix(refName, refPrefix) {
        continue
    }
    branchName := refName[len(refPrefix):]
    fmt.Println(branchName)
}
```

But, this involves cloning the repo first.
How can I get the list without cloning the repo ?

Thanks in advence !

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `git ls-remote --heads` lists all heads (branches) on a given remote even if you've never ran `fetch` on the local repo. If your library has an API equivalent to that, it should be enough for your needs.

Comment: I don't really know go but this seems to be the appropriate method: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5#Remote.List

Comment: @kalatabe, I have mentioned the same method in the code snippet, but my goal was to somehow skip the Plainclone process. I am able to do it now with "NewRemote" method